# Wifi Direct between linux & android

Tags: linux, wifi, android, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect linux and android via Wifi Direct, especially Odroid-C1 and Galaxy S7.
By using wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli, I successed make wifi direct connection, So Android shows Wifi Direct Connected as you can see below.(in the red rectangle)

[image]

The question is HOW CAN I DO SOMETHING like file transfer, even send PINGs!

In the wifi direct between two linux systems, each IP address can easily set, so I could use FTP or SSH.
But the android, it is hard to know it's IP address, and almost every wifi direct app does not working.

Does anyone have clue about this situation??

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving what you want is by assigning a static IP address to one of the devices say the device running Linux for example:

> `ifconfig p2p-interface 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

(modify to match your own, where p2p-interface is the interface created for p2p communication after running wpa_supplicant, on my device it is p2p-wlan0-0 )

and on the other device, in your case the android phone, connect to that IP address using your application.